# How to enable zstd for your qcow2 files

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, qcow2

In QEMU 5.1 zstd compression of your qcow2 files was introduced but I can't find a way to activate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an option for the `qemu-img create` command, so it's only possible to use zstd when creating new images e.g. `qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o compression_type=zstd ./test-with-zstd.qcow2 10`

I guess it provide continuous compression in contrast to the current "old" compression feature which didn't.

@openSUSE: Time of writing is was not enabled in the package ([bug report](https://bugzilla.opensuse.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1185310)) :-(